# Visual Studio Code auto import third party modules

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyside2

A couple of version ago, I was able auto import a module from a suggestion based on imports I have already made.

Examples

```py
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (
   QPushButton
)

# by writing Q, I has given a list of modules to auto import from `PySide2.QtWidgets` module
label = Q
```

Now I am on the same project, same interpreter, same settings, but I am no longer offered those suggestions from the `PySide2.QtWidgets` but only from built-in modules and current directory.

[image]

I also have the settings `python.analysis.indexing` on `true` but I don't see any effect.

How to enable auto imports from third party modules?

EDIT: While I am waiting for an answer, I made my own extension as a quick workaround:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/manage/publishers/virgilsisoe/extensions/python-auto-import/hub?_a=acquisition